# .NET Core 2.0 MVC odd 404 on controller methods only when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

My home controller sucessfully return `index.html` from

`http://localhost/` 
and

`http://localhost/controller/`

but if i try to hit

`http://localhost/controller/method/`

I get a `404` even though that method works fine in IIS express.

Couldn't find anything online with someone having a similar issue where only the methods on a controller didn't work on one particular deployment but the controller itself is fine.

Things I've Tried that were common among a lot of .Net Core 2.0 issues with IIS Deployments:

- Make sure windows authentication is on in project settings and in IIS (I've toggled it on and off to no avail on both I don't have user auth on my web app so I don't think this matters for me).
- Switched my application pool to use `No managed code` for `CLR` version
- Change application pool ID to be `LocalSystem`
- Change permissions on my publish output folder to include `%hostname%\IIS_IUSRS`

Pretty sure I've also tried a lot of other basic troubleshooting that sometimes fixes issues. I.E. removing and readding app. Turning things on and off again to no avail.

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot this would be very welcome.

I also want to note it was working yesterday and can't remember changing anything other than the publishing output to use `Debug` instead of `Release` which of course by now I've changed back to `Release` but still no luck.

Here is some code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Store([FromBody]MyObject obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Request.Body);
        //Some code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Check(string objectUID, string idfv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ObjectUID: {objectUID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IDFV: {idfv}");
        //some other code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public MyObject Retrieve(string objectUID)
    {
        Console.Writeline($"ObjectUID: {objectUID}");
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

This is my routing.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=MyController}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: can you show some code? Controller-method and Route-Attributes?

Comment: @Nikolaus I added some code as you can see its very basic controller class. I'm new to `.net` and MVC and web development my understanding is that I don't need Route-Attributes since MVC will create the endpoint to be the name of the method. It works in IIS Express this way anyway. Do you recommend I do Route-Attribution to see if that fixes it? not sure why would work in IIS express

Comment: In Program.cs  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) adds IISIntegration support. Also, in Startup.cs file, app.UseMvc(); automatically setups default routing {controller}/{action} so no need for custom attribute based routing

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: No, `app.UseMvc()` does not setup default routing for you man. `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` does.

Comment: Read IIS log files to see what is the sub status.

Comment: @DavidLiang My routing looks the same as if I had used `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` so I do not believe that is the issue.

Comment: @NSGangster: yea my reply was to @MohsinMehmood as he was saying to just use `app.UseMvc()` without the configuration you had, which is wrong. You either config the routes like you did, or just use the default route configuration by calling `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`.Back to your issue, did you publish the app to a virtual directory?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Also, if you have Parameters, which names differ from id, Attribute-Routing is a way to prevent errors.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue and if not, could you add what your request looks like?

Comment: Getting a similar thing with an API controller. did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 0):

If you‘re not sure why it doesn’t work, try Attribute-Routing, explained in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
Then you could try it this way:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Store([FromBody]MyObject obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Request.Body);
        //Some code
    }
    // If you have a parameter from the uri or query-string, you can add it to the Template this way
    [HttpGet("{objectUID} ")]
    public void Check(string objectUID, string idfv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ObjectUID: {objectUID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IDFV: {idfv}");
        //some other code
    }
    // Or optional parameter like this 
    [HttpGet ("{objectUID?} ")]
    public MyObject Retrieve(string objectUID)
    {
        Console.Writeline($"ObjectUID: {objectUID}");
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try perhaps sometime tonight and get back to you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting 404 error, I suspect the aspnet core handler is missing from your website. Assuming that you have .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed, 
ensure you have the following handler added in the web.config file. If web.config file is missing add a new web.config. Also, add a logs folder at the website root folder for logging.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

I got ASP.NET Core 2 app running on my machine following these steps:

1. App Pool setting run under AppPoolIdentity with No Managed runtime configuration
2. Publish your ASP.NET Core 2 website to a folder. By default it publishes to bin\Release\PublishOutput
3. Point your IIS website to published folder

Comment: Ty for a quick response, I have done that. I couldn't even get to my home controller before then i would receive a 500.19 previous to this change.

Comment: I updated my answer and got the ASP.NET Core application running on my development following the steps mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with getting a 404 when trying to access my site's Account controller. All of the other Razor pages where working correctly. If I change the inheritInChildApplications="false" to true in the web.config the controller starts working.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="true">
   ...
</configuration>`